# Dell Latitude BIOS: firmware update failed

Tags: windows-10, bios, updates, dell-latitude

I have downloaded a critical BIOS update

> Precision_3560_Latitude_5520_1.27.0.exe

When I run it on Latitude 5520 with Windows 10 x64 22H2 I get

> Error: Firmware update failed Note: [String 10000078 is not found].
> Please Update Resource file

I have BitLocker on and I have a BIOS password set.
It is the second BIOS update in a row that I am unable to install using DELL installer from Windows. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the checkbox

> Automatically suspend BitLocker

from the update installer does not work and produces above mentioned error.

I have suspended BitLocker from control panel and everything went ok.

- Open Control Panel.
- Select System and Security > BitLocker Drive Encryption > Suspend protection.
- Select Yes